# Почему последний элемент из БД выводит NULL ( используется RedBeanPHP)?

Tags: php, redbeanphp

В базе данных есть таблица 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Столбцы имеют такие характеристики 
[image: Столбцы имеют такие характеристики]

**Команда выводит нужную строку**

```
echo R::load('name_table', 113);  //  выводит строку из таблицы name_table, которая содержит значение 113
//ВЫВОДИТ ПО ПОРЯДКУ: {"id":"113","name_pay_link":"Мой первый товар","price_pay_link":"154","url_pay_link":"https:www.google.ru","idUser":"104"}
```

**Почему может не выводиться последний столбец? idUser** 
 
По очереди выводим значение каждого столбца у этой строки

```
$uniq_id= R::load('name_table', 113);  // читаем строку из таблицы name_table, где нашли значение 113

echo $uniq_id->id; // ВЫВОДИТ 113
echo $uniq_id->name_pay_link; // ВЫВОДИТ Мой первый товар
echo $uniq_id->price_pay_link; // ВЫВОДИТ 154
echo $uniq_id->url_pay_link; // ВЫВОДИТ https://www.google.ru
echo $uniq_id->idUser; // ВЫВОДИТ ПУСТОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИ, var_dump говорит NULL
```

**p.s.** `var_dump($uniq_id)` **выдает следующее**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикрепите к вопросу вывод `var_dump($uniq_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При доступе к свойству объекта: `$uniq_id->idUser`, неявно происходит вызов магического метода `__get($property)`, в теле которого проверяется регистр букв у запрошенного свойства и если оно не состоит только из символов нижнего регистра - вызывается функция [beau](https://github.com/gabordemooij/redbean/blob/d1491a6ba5d8b5d7c2171e575101e53ecb17976a/RedBeanPHP/OODBBean.php#L1097)($property), которая преобразует название у свойства из camelCase в название в нижнем регистре с подчеркиванием: `idUser` -> `id_user`.

Чтобы не переименовать название поля `idUser` в таблице, можно запросить все значения в виде ассоциативного массива, привести его к объекту и получать из него значения:

```
$uniq_id = (object)R::load('name_table', 113)->getProperties();
echo $uniq_id->userId;
```

Comment: Спасибо за очень профессиональное решение!

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию redbeanphp не может считывать символы в верхнем регистре.

Решение задачи:

Переименовать `idUser` на `iduser`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Кто бы мог подумать. Несколько дней по форумам бегаю, никто ответа не знал... Вот и первый баг пошел =)